# What are the advantages of using <div> elements over <table>?

Tags: html

Is there any advantage of using div elements instead of tables in HTML page design?

Comment: Because I didn't see it jump out at me in the linked duplicate questions, I wanted to add one area where CSS layout provides a HUGE advantage over tables:  GOOGLE is much better at correctly indexing css layouts.  Using style sheets there can give you a decent SEO bump.